# Angular UI Router: Default nested view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following:

```
.state('account', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/account',
    templateUrl: 'pages/templates/account.html',
    controller: 'account'
})

.state('account.settings', { 
    url: '/settings', 
    templateUrl: 'pages/templates/account.settings.html', 
    controller: 'account.settings'
})

.state('account.user', { 
    url: '/user', 
    templateUrl: 'pages/templates/account.user.html', 
    controller: 'account.user'
})
```

I am trying to make it so if I go to:

```
/account => it goes to /account/settings
/account/setting => goes to /account/settings
/account/user => goes to /account/user
```

Basically making account.settings the default.

Is there a way to do this?

---

The big reason I want to do this is because of the following (maybe someone has a better suggestion for a work around)

I have a link like so:

```
<a ui-sref="account.settings" ui-sref-active="active">Account<a>
```

I'd like it to have the `active` class regardless of what nested view (settings or user). But I want this link to always send the user to `account.settings`.

If anyone could help me out, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May be able to add a resolve method on the route. `resolve: function() { $location.path("/account/settings"); }` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.state('account', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/account',
    templateUrl: 'pages/templates/account.html',
    controller: 'account'
})
.state('account.settings', { 
    url: '', 
    templateUrl: 'pages/templates/account.settings.html', 
    controller: 'account.settings'
})

.state('account.settings2', { 
    url: '/settings', 
    templateUrl: 'pages/templates/account.settings.html', 
    controller: 'account.settings'
})

.state('account.user', { 
    url: '/user', 
    templateUrl: 'pages/templates/account.user.html', 
    controller: 'account.user'
})
```

Or redirect from the abstract to the concrete state... the code snippet removes the specified 'account' controller reference, but the code in the snippet can be added to the controller if needed:

```
.state('account', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/account',
    templateUrl: 'pages/templates/account.html',
    controller: ['$scope', '$state', 
        function( $scope, $state) {
            $state.go('account.settings');
        }], 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! I'd still want the url to get redirected to `/account/settings` though; i'm not sure this would do it.

Comment: Misunderstood what you wanted to do... I've edited my response to show an example of how to redirect from abstract to concrete state.